# From File[] files to directory

Tags: java, file

I have a problem with that code:

```
public class Files {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // filter files AAA.txt and BBB.txt from another's
        File f = new File("d:\\dir"); // current directory
        File f1 = new File("d:\\dir1\\");


        FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

                if (name.startsWith("A") && name.endsWith(".TXT")) {
                    //System.out.println(name);
                    return true;
                }
                else if (name.startsWith("B") && name.endsWith(".TXT")) {
                    //System.out.println(name);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    //System.out.println(name);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        File[] files = f.listFiles(textFilter);
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.getName().startsWith("A") ) {
                //here save file to d:\\folder1\\
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I save files with specific name in example AAA.txt to folder1 and BBB.txt to folder 2. Thanks for any examples

Comment: For better chances to get help, format your code properly

Comment: Are you having trouble generating the new filename? Or are you having trouble saving the file? Do you want to copy the file to its new location or move it? Is it safe to assume all of the directories here are on the same filesystem?

Comment: Move it the file. Sumit Singh answer is very good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class from Java 7:
Use [move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
...
for (File file : files) {    
  if (file.getName().startsWith("A") ) {
     //here save file to d:\\folder1\\
     // convert file to Path object use toPath() method.
     Path targetFilePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("d:\\folder1\\").resolve(file.getFileName())
     Files.move(file.toPath(), targetFilePath , REPLACE_EXISTING);
  }
}
```